# Customizing dynamic font style and size in a custom dialog box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dialog

I created my own custom message/dialog box already in xaml (view) and  I have a viewmodel that raises the message property. I bind the message property to a textblock inside my xaml.

Now I am wondering one thing, how can I change the font style and size of a specific dynamic string inside my viewmodel?

Since my messages are different for every viewmodel I have.

E.g.in every viewmodel, I have something like

```
messagewindow.Message = "This is a new message";
dialogService.ShowDialog(Success, messageWindow);
```

In one of my messages, I want to make the font bold and different color/size for a specific message segment.

How can I do that without messing up with the other messages that inherit from the xaml or code behind?

Currently, I'm not using any code behind and a lot of the examples online I've seen use code behind and/or don't have dynamic message textboxes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a couple of ways I think. In your ViewModel create props that you need to change. For example MessageFontWeight:

```
FontWeight _fw;
public FontWeight MessageFontWeight
        {
            get { return _fw; }
            set
            {
                if (_fw != value)
                {
                    _fw = value;

                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageFontWeight);
                }
            }
        }
```

In Xaml bind it to a prop of TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontWeight="{Binding MessageFontWeight }"/>
```

Then you can:

```
messagewindow.Message = "This is a new message";
messagewindow.MessageFontWeight=FontWeights.Heavy;
dialogService.ShowDialog(Success, messageWindow);
```

(in VM constructor you may want to set the default value `MessageFontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;`)

The more interesting way is to replace the textblock in your View with `ContentControl`. In Your VM create a property for your control:

```
object  _messageControl; 
public object MessageControl
           {
               get { return _messageControl; }
               set
               {
                   if (_messageControl!= value)
                   {
                       _messageControl = value;
                       RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageControl);
                   }
               }
           }
```

In your Xaml:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MessageControl}"/>
```

And pass to a VM constructor or as you did the control you like:

```
    TextBlock message = new TextBlock();
                message.Text = "Message Text";
                message.FontSize = 27;
                message.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);

    messagewindow.MessageControl= message;
    dialogService.ShowDialog(Success, messageWindow);
```

With this approach you can pass controls of any complexity – in stackpanels, grids etc.

**EDIT**
According to your question in comments you need different styling inside one TextBlock. I would strongly recommend you the second way that I sugested.
You can do the folowing:

```
TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
tb1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
Run s1 = new Run(string1);
s1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Run s2 = new Run(string2);
s2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
tb1.Inlines.Add(s1); 
tb1.Inlines.Add(s2);
messagewindow.MessageControl= tb1;
dialogService.ShowDialog(Success, messageWindow);
```

Nice and easy I suppose.
If you want to use only this syntax as you showed `messageWindow.Message = string1 + string2` then you should have two additional props in your viewModel. String1 and String2, declare them as standard props with `RaisePropertyChanged`. when you pass `string1+string2` to Message there should be some splitter between them - `string1+"^"+string2` + Then use in to your Message prop should look like:

```
public string Message
                   {
  get { 
    return _message; 
    }
    set
    {
     if (_message!= value)
     {
     _message = value;
        string[] str=value.Split('^');
        String1=str[0];
        String2=str[1];
       RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
       }
      }
    }
```

Finally XAML Code of your View:

```
<TextBlock>
<Run Text="{Binding String1}"/>
<Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding String2}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: For your first method, I am getting an error on this line: "RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageFontWeight);" It says Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is a not a delegate type. What does that mean? Can't I just raise RaisepropertyChanged("MessageFontWeight")?

Comment: @KalaJ, sorry for that, my class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface uses lambdas not just string with a name of property. Of course if you have other implementation use your own) Its just an exemple))

Comment: Hi Den, Thanks for your help! It Works but one problem. I have a string in this format: messageWindow.Message = string1 + string2; I only want string2 to be bold and not string1 even though they're concatenated. How can do that? Thanks a lot for your help again!!

Comment: @KalaJ, please refer to the Edit in my answer

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks @Den